# Upgrading Chrome stable aptitude reports version 39 but chrome://chrome reports 38

Tags: apt, upgrade, google-chrome

I am trying to upgrade google chrome to the latest stable release.

I used apt-get purge google-chrome-stable to remove and then installed the lastest through the PPA

```
/opt/google/chrome$ apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable:
Installed: 39.0.2171.71-1
Candidate: 39.0.2171.71-1
Version table:
*** 39.0.2171.71-1 0
500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

However the about page lists Version 38.0.2125.122 (64-bit)

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the latest deb package manually
 and install it. When you install that deb package via Software center, PPA will be added automatically. there is no need of any complications